# Authenticating SQL connection using AD login details outside the domain

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am trying to connect to a SQL server from outside the domain.

I have the following connection string:

```
SqlConnection("SERVER=Server;DATABASE=Database;User ID=Domain\User;Password=password");
```

When I try to use this outside the domain this will fail as it tries to log in using SQL authentication.

Is there any way to pass a command into the string to use Active Directory authentication.

What other ways would there be to connect to a SQL server, using active directory details outside of the domain?

Comment: can you give us more details??

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to generate sql user and use it ?

Comment: Would need to create hundreds of users on a number of SQL servers. This hasnt been a problem with this specific app before, but the app is going to be used outside the domain.

Comment: Why would you need to create 100s of users - are you creating a 2 tier or three tier app?  If it's two tier (thick app accessing SQL directly), then don't - create a middle tier using a single SQL account.

Comment: Nope, its stuck on the back burner at the moment. Thinking there is no options other than manually adding user accounts or creating a intermediate service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to:

1. Use Integrated Security in your connection string and create a domain trust relationship between your resource domain (where SQL server is) and your account domain (where the account is). Or...
2. Create an account in SQL Server and use that in your connection string as user name and password.

You're doing an invalid mix by putting domain credentials in user/pass and there's not even a trust relationship.

EDIT:

The comments indicate a need to sync SQL account with AD creds.  This is not needed.  A sql account is simply SQL scoped user name and password which is specific to SQL server and has nothing to do with domain creds.  If you use SQL account, then those become a configuration setting in your app which is used to construct the proper connection and sent over the wire.  SQL server authenticates those creds locally without involving AD.

It's also interesting whether you create a 2-tier (fat client accessing sql directly) or 3-tier (clients access your middle tier app server which accesses sql).  If it's the latter, your application authenticates and authorizes users and after that, it uses a config setting with the sql specific user/pass in it to access sql.  If it's the former and you're using sql accounts then you need one per client and that's a problem.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the App is going to be used along a PPTP VPN tunnel, which means there is no gaurentee that the PC that is connected will be part of a domain, so it is not even possible to trust these other domains. The problem with creating SQL accounts would be keeping the SQL passwords aligned with AD.

Comment: Who says the SQL account has to align/be in-sync with the AD account.  The username is already different (just account - not domain\account).  What that means is it's a configuration setting in the app which is used to build the connnection string.

Comment: Wouldn't the server being part of the network where the domain is and impersonate on be enough?

Comment: If you specify "Integrated" auth in the connection string.  If you specify a sql username/pass, then impersonation has nothing to do with it per your instruction.